# Can't check one variable in if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a one problem.  This is code:

```
var z = "+"
if (z!="+" || z!="-" || z!="*" || z!="/" || z!="%") document.write("You must give me operator (+ - * / %)");
else
document.write("Yess!");
```

**OUTPUT IS: You must give me operator (+ - * / %)**

Why it doesn't work  correctly?
Thank's for help. :)

Comment: `||` is OR. So if `z!="+" OR z!="-"...`. So you have `false OR true...` which is, `true`, obviously. Always.

Comment: you have to use `&&` instead `||` here

Answer (score 2):

You should not do an OR, but an AND:

```
var z = "+"
if (z!="+" && z!="-" && z!="*" && z!="/" && z!="%") document.write("You must give me operator (+ - * / %)");
else
    document.write("Yess!");
```

Comment: This is why using a `switch` statement, a lookup table, a regular expression, or an array of allowed values might be preferable.

Comment: @tadman: Because you might mix up `&&` and `||`? That hardly seems like a good reason to use `switch`

Comment: @MattBurland I mean because this sort of pattern quickly becomes a mess when you add on more and more things. Since the author misunderstood it, that alone speaks to how it's not always easy to read. Some other pattern would be better. `switch` is just one example.

Comment: It mostly depends on the broader context this code sits in.

Comment: @tadman: How many more mathematical operators do you think they are likely to add? Probably not many. I'm not saying you're wrong. Something like an array or string with `indexOf` might be cleaner, but not because you might mix up `&&` and `||`

Comment: @MattBurland That's why I like Tresdin's answer. The advantage of a `switch` is you can break out the logic for each operator as you encounter it, then have a default condition where you complain. That avoids testing and later interpreting something. Don't think these things stay simple forever. There's a lot of potential operators here.

Answer (score 2):

You better check it like this.

```
var z = "+";
document.write('+-*/%'.indexOf(z) !== -1 ? "Yess!" : "You must give me operator (+ - * / %)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using "AND" not "OR" because with "OR" any one of your conditions being true will make the ENTIRE condition true and since `z != "-"`, that's enough to move you into the true branch of the `if`.

```js
var z = "+";

if (z != "+" && z != "-" && z != "*" && z != "/" && z != "%") {
  document.write("You must give me operator (+ - * / %)");
} else {
  document.write("Yess!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Breakdown the logic.

If z must be equal to "+" and z can not equal "+" || "-" || "*" || "/" || "%" , then z must be true.

This is true because each logical comparison is not conditional to any other comparison when using OR. If any logical comparison is satisfied such as z is not equal to "/" , this statement must be true since z = "+" and not equal to "/" .

*This is why you must use AND in your logical statement to get your desired out come.